# Correspondence between \setsansfont arguments and system font names

Tags: xetex, fontspec

If one were to download and install a font called `HelveticaNeueLTStd-It.otf` on a W10 system with MikTeX (compiling with XeLaTeX), do we expect that the call

```
\setsansfont[
        Ligatures=TeX,
        ...
        ItalicFont={Helvetica Neue Light Italic},
        ...
    ]{Helvetica Neue Light}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
```

to point back to the installed font?  It seems to me that the argument of `\setsansfont` should match either the font file name or an identifier stored in the `.otf` file.

Comment: I'm not totally sure what the question is. If you process that code, then `\sfdefault` ends up with the value `HelveticaNeueLight(0)`. Are you asking where the `(0)` comes from? (It would be helpful to make your code compilable.)  Or are you asking why you load the font with the name `Helvetica Neue Light`?

Comment: The name supplied to `\setsanstfont` is the Family name, as reported by e.g. `otfinfo -i HelveticaNeueLTStd-It.otf` (Not sure if this command works on Windows.)